# Redirect to specific url instead of login page in PermissionCheckerAttribute class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, permissions

for authorization in the project I've created PermissionCkeckerAttribute class and this class is extend of AuthorizeAttribute class and IAuthorizationFilter interface

in the implementation method of the AuthorizeAttribute I inject my service and with if statement I check if the user is authenticated or not if the user IsAuthenticated but does not have permission with RedirectResult() method will redirect to NotFound page so here its work correctly but in the else statement when the user does not Authentication and dose not logged in I want to redirect to NotFound page but RedirectResult() dose not work and automatically redirect to Login page how to fix it should I use another method?

here is my code

```
  public class PermissionCheckerAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
 {
     private IUserServices _userServices;
     private int _permissionId = 0;
     public PermissionCheckerAttribute(int permissionId)
     {
             _permissionId = permissionId;
     }
     public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
     {
         _userServices = (IUserServices)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IUserServices));

         if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         {
             var phoneNumber = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

             if (!_userServices.CheckPermission(_permissionId, phoneNumber))
             {
                 context.Result = new RedirectResult("/NotFound");
             }

            
            
         }
         else
         {
//here automatically redirect to login page but I want to redirect to NotFound page 

             context.Result = new RedirectResult("/NotFound");
         }

     }
 }
```

try to redirect to Notfound Page but PermissionChecker redirect to Login page automatically

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing the default behavior, to override you could try using the below code:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    _userServices = (IUserServices)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IUserServices));

    if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var phoneNumber = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        if (!_userServices.CheckPermission(_permissionId, phoneNumber))
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("/NotFound");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404; 
        context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(404); 
    }
}
```